# NGINX lua use secure_link_md5 from env var

Tags: nginx, lua, environment-variables

I'm using NGINX with lua support to accesses hostnames and other App releated variables from my .env file.
Now i wanted to use the secure_link_md5 var. from a .env file but i dont understand how to put together the string so that nginx can understand it.

This is how my nginx config looks like:

```
env LINK_SECRET;

set_by_lua $curr_dl_link_secret 'return os.getenv("LINK_SECRET")'; # Needs to be set correctly
secure_link_md5 = "${curr_dl_link_secret}$uri$secure_link_expires";
```

Normaly i would set the config line like that without the use of lua and env vars:

```
secure_link_md5 "XGc7YyXERjiSvs4PtzpnBMANuFd22VAmXDc66g6JU$uri$secure_link_expires";
```

Currently NGINX always returns the following error:

> invalid number of arguments in "secure_link_md5"

Answer (score 0):

NGINX counts "=" as an argument. I am not familiar with NGINX with lua, but I think "{}" are also unnecessary.

I guess you want something like this:

```
secure_link_md5 "$curr_dl_link_secret$uri$secure_link_expires";
```